# NiFi - Persist timestamp value used in ExecuteSQLRecord processor query

Tags: apache-nifi

My use-case is simple but I did not find the right solution so-far.

I write the query which tag the data with the current timestamp in of the column at the time ExecuteSQLRecord processor hit and get the data from database now want I wanted is that created flowfile has to have the same timestamp in his name as well but i did not know how to capture the attribute which is `${now():format("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}` so I can use alter for renaming the flowfile

Basically, I wanted to store the timestamp "at the time I hit the database", I can not use the update processor just before the executeSQL processor to get the timestamp needed (why => because if prior execution is still in process with executeSQL and all the flow files will pass updateattribute processor with the timestamp value and will sit in the queue until executeSQL processor process current thread).

Note - I am running NiFi in standalone mode so I can not run executeSQL in multiple threads.

Any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: You want to put your attribute's value inside your flowfile?

Comment: yes, update the flowfile with the timestamp which I have done in a query but the second part is tricky when I wanted to use the same timestamp value to update the same flowfile name

Comment: If you want to just put the attribute inside the content, try using the processor ReplaceText and put your attribute in the replacement field. You can select the mode Append if you just want to gather this information in the end of your content.

Comment: that timestamp has to be added into each row of my flowfile content, I am having csv format inside the flowfile and that timestamp column shows the processing time which the same I wanted to use later in filename for that flowfile

Comment: In this case, you can use ReplaceText with Regex Replace option.

Comment: Put (.*) as the regex pattern and $1,${your-attribute} as replacement and set the option to apply in each line of your content

Comment: but considering I have started pulling data using executeSQL processor and it took around 30 mins to complete, so case1) I can use replacetext processor just after executeSQL  for timestamp population which will not be right at it started 30 min before

Comment: case2) if I populate the timestamp just before executeSQL both the replacement and filename can be done correctly but if in case if few more new request come and queued up before executeSQL processor then all the queued ones will have the much earlier timestamp which is again wrong(that timestamp has to be considered only when you hit the database not in the queue, not after process time), I love you hear your input #REsteves

Comment: In this case, wouldnt it be easier if you select the timestamp from your database in your query?

Comment: Yeah, that what I am doing I added another field name process_tsp which I evaluated at the time of query into the database, like `select *,'${now():format("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}' as process_tsp from tbl`, but how can I make available this `${now():format("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}` later for filenaming convention, that is the problem I have !!!

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteSQLRecord writes an attribute called `executesql.query.duration` which contains the duration of the query + fetch in milliseconds.

So, we can put an UpdateAttribute processor AFTER the ExecuteSQLRecord that uses `${now():toNumber():minus(${executesql.query.duration})}` to get the current time as Epoch Millis, then minus the total query duration, to get the time at which the Query started.

You can then use `:format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')` to bring it back to the timestamp format you want.

It might be a few milliseconds off of the exact time (time taken to get to the UpdateAttribute processor).

[See docs for ExecuteSQLRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQLRecord/)